# How do I kill a daemon and not have it open up again if I can't find it in the LaunchAgents or LaunchDaemons?

Tags: macos, launchd, startup, plist, daemons

So I think I downloaded a program from Avatron called Airconnect. I'm not sure, but their website was purple when I looked it up. Anyway, now everytime I check my activity monitor, `com.avatron.airconnect.daemon` is taking at least 25% of my CPU. What have I done.

I tried looking up a solution online, and I realized it opens with launchd (I checked through activity monitor), so my research directed me towards `System/Library/LaunchAgents`, `System/Library/LaunchDaemons`, or `Library/LaunchAgents`. I tried looking through all of the folders, and I can't find the airconnect daemon. Please help me. I thought I was smarter than to get viruses. I am so disappointed in myself now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The launch daemon of Avatron Airconnect is installed to /Library/LaunchDaemons. If you want to stop and remove it enter in Terminal:

- Check if it is loaded:

  ```
  sudo launchctl list | grep avatron
  ```
- Unload it:

  ```
  sudo launchctl stop /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.avatron.airconnect.daemon.plist
  sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.avatron.airconnect.daemon.plist
  ```
- To remove it:

  ```
  sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.avatron.airconnect.daemon.plist
  ```

---

After installing Avatron Airconnect you can uninstall the app from the Airconnect menulet! This should also remove the launch daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Software you personally install typically puts its files in several places under your [username]/Library or ~/Library. While holding down the Option key, use the Finder's Go menu to open your Library folder. Check under ~/Library/Application Support, ~/Library/LaunchAgents & ~/Library/Preferences for any files with Avatron or AirConnect in their names & delete them. That should cure your problem.
BTW- this isn't a virus.